# Is there a universal age of adulthood recognized by UFOP?

Tags: star-trek, federation

In the galaxy, [lifespans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Life_span) are ridiculously varied, from Kes' species becoming adults at about age 2 to the effectively immortal Trill.  I know that UFOP doesn't dominate the entire galaxy, but does it have an actual 'age' that it considers someone to be an adult (especially for legal reasons), or is it a species-by-species case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the (kinda) canon sourcebook; [The Starfleet Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual), Articles 2, 3 and 7 of the Federation Charter specifically state that as long as a Federation member is respecting the individual rights of their citizens, the UFP has no authority to interfere in the **domestic social system** of its individual members.

Making decisions on [age of majority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority) would certainly fall well inside this description.

[image: Federation Charter 1]

[image: Federation Charter 2]

Note that the charter does create pressure on members to promote the fundamental principle of promoting and encouraging respect for all life forms.